# Unable to access the IIS in VS 2013?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting the below error message when trying to load a website in VS 2013.

```
Unable to access the IIS metabase.You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS websites on your machine.
```

I have Admin rights for my machine. I tried running VS 2013 as administrator and also tried changing the IIS configuration in the control panel and restarting the machine.

However, I am still getting same error message. What can I do to fix the above error?

Comment: Format your pc and reinstall the studio. That worked for me.